# XSD to validate namespaced attributes on non-namespaced elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have been asked to create schemas for validating documents whose structures were developed before XML Schema became a thing. None of the elements have a colon in the name, but some of the attributes do. It seems that in theory it should be possible to do it with something like this:

```
$ cat repro.xsd
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="" xmlns:x="namespace-x" targetNamespace="">
 <xsd:import namespace="namespace-x" schemaLocation="repro.inc"/>
 <xsd:element name="a" type="a"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="a">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
   <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:attribute ref="x:y"/>
   </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
$ cat repro.inc
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="namespace-x">
 <xsd:attribute name="y" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

But the schema validator complains:

```
$ cat repro.xml
<a xmlns:x="namespace-x" x:y="foo"/>
$ xmllint --schema repro.xsd repro.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a xmlns:x="namespace-x" x:y="foo"/>
repro.xml:1: element a: Schemas validity error : Element 'a': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
repro.xml fails to validate
```

Doesn't `targetNamespace=""` mean the elements defined in this schema document don't use a namespace? If not, how does one go about validating such documents using XML Schema?

Unfortunately, putting the elements in a namespace without a prefix (`xmlns="other-ns"`) would break a very large quantity of software which uses namespace-aware parsers, so a solution along those lines is unappealing.

Comment: Clearly stated question with a nice [mcve].  Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43307918/290085) below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't targetNamespace="" mean the elements defined in this schema
>   document don't use a namespace? If not, how does one go about
>   validating such documents using XML Schema?

No, the value of `targetNamespace` must never be empty; simply omit `targetNamespace` for no namespace instead.  You can also remove `xmlns=""` from `xsd:schema`.

### repro.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:x="namespace-x">
  <xsd:import namespace="namespace-x" schemaLocation="repro.inc"/>
  <xsd:element name="a" type="a"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="a">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute ref="x:y"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**repro.inc** and **repro.xml** are fine as they are.

With the above changes, your XSD will validate your XML successfully.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought I had tried that, resulting in an error messages telling me my xsd:import wasn't allowed, because it targeted a namespace when the importing schema did not. However, I must have been moving too fast, because taking the targetNamespace back out of the master schema's top element didn't produce that same error (and allowed the schema to work as expected, just as you said it would).